# while sending and receiving telnet stream asynchronously, while loop hangs the telnet emulator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, signalr, telnet

I am working on telnet emulator in web using mvc with signalR, while sending and receiving telnet stream asynchronously while loop hangs the page if kept for long, does not finish. Tried many solution but no luck.

Below is code where it stuck while continuously looking for stream bytes.

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Wait for data from the telnet server and send it to the emulation.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task ReadLoop(string connectionId, BaseDecoder decoder, CancellationToken ct, string PanelId)
    {
        var client = Get(connectionId);
        if (client == null) { return; }
        string script = string.Empty;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(panelScript))
        {
            panelScript = objAccn.ExecuteQueryPanelScript(Convert.ToInt32(PanelId)).ToString();
            script = panelScript.Replace(@"\n", Environment.NewLine);
            commands = Regex.Split(script, "\r\n");
        }

        string loginPrompt = null;
        if (PanelId != "1")

            loginPrompt = "login: ";
        else
            loginPrompt = "name?: ";
        var login = commands[0];// WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["login"];
        if (!_panelCommands.ContainsKey(0))
            _panelCommands.Add(0, true);
        var passwordPrompt = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["passwordPrompt"];
        var password = commands[1];//WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
        if (!_panelCommands.ContainsKey(1))
            _panelCommands.Add(1, true);
        var loginAuto = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(loginPrompt) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(login));
        var passwordAuto = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordPrompt) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(password));
        var DefaultCommandsForm60 = false;
        var DefaultCommandsForm50 = false;
        var DefaultScreenm50 = false;
        decoder.ScriptFunc = async (string str) =>
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                {
                    if (loginAuto && str.EndsWith(loginPrompt, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        await client.StreamWriter.WriteAsync(login + "\r\n");
                        loginAuto = false;
                        str = str.Remove(str.Length - loginPrompt.Length);
                    }
                    if (passwordAuto && str.EndsWith(passwordPrompt, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        await client.StreamWriter.WriteAsync(password + "\r\n");
                        passwordAuto = false;
                        str = str.Remove(str.Length - passwordPrompt.Length);
                        if (PanelId != "1")
                            DefaultCommandsForm60 = true;
                        else
                            DefaultCommandsForm50 = true;
                        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    }
                    if (PanelId != "1")
                    {
                        if (DefaultCommandsForm60)
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                            await client.StreamWriter.WriteAsync(commands[2] + "\r\n");
                            if (commands.Length > 2)
                            {
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                                await client.StreamWriter.WriteAsync(commands[3] + "\r\n");
                            }
                            if (commands.Length > 3)
                            {
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                                await client.StreamWriter.WriteAsync(commands[4] + "\r\n");
                            }
                            DefaultCommandsForm60 = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if (DefaultCommandsForm50)
                        {
                            if (commands.Length > 1)
                            {
                                //  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
                                if (!_panelCommands.ContainsKey(3))
                                {
                                    // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                                    await client.StreamWriter.WriteAsync(commands[3] + "\r\n");
                                    _panelCommands.Add(3, true);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (commands.Length > 2)
                                    {
                                        if (!_panelCommands.ContainsKey(4))
                                        {
                                            // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                                            await client.StreamWriter.WriteAsync(commands[3] + "\r\n");
                                            _panelCommands.Add(4, true);
                                        }
                                        DefaultCommandsForm50 = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                DefaultScreenm50 = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (DefaultScreenm50)
                                if (str.EndsWith("$ "))
                                {
                                    await client.StreamWriter.WriteAsync("Screen" + "\r\n");
                                    str = str.Remove(str.Length - ("$ ").Length);
                                    DefaultScreenm50 = false;
                                }
                        }

                    }
                }
                return str;
            };

        const int bufferSize = 4096;
        //if (ns.CanRead)
        //{
        //    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        //    int numBytesRead = 0;
        //    do
        //    {
        //        numBytesRead = ns.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
        //        //var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readBuffer);
        //        // ss= Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(readBuffer.ToArray());
        //        //sb.Append(readBuffer[0].ToString);
        //        sb.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, numBytesRead));
        //        sb.Replace(Convert.ToChar(24), ' ');
        //        sb.Replace(Convert.ToChar(255), ' ');
        //        sb.Replace('?', ' ');
        //        //sb.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />").ToString();
        //    }
        //    while (ns.DataAvailable);
        //}
        //if (client._stream.CanRead)
        //{
        //    do
        //    {
        //        var inBytes = await client.ReadAsync(bufferSize, ct);
        //        foreach (var b in inBytes)
        //        {
        //            await decoder.AddByte(b);
        //        }
        //        await decoder.Flush();
        //    } while (client.IsConnected );
        ////}
        //Disconnect(connectionId);
 //var  readTask = client.ReadAsync(bufferSize, ct);
        while (client.IsConnected && !ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (client._stream.CanRead)
            {
                var inBytes = await client.ReadAsync(bufferSize, ct);
                foreach (var b in inBytes)
                {
                    await decoder.AddByte(b);
                }

                await decoder.Flush();
            }
        }
        Disconnect(connectionId);
    }
}
```

In above method here the part of code where it stuck and never comes to an end.

```
while (client.IsConnected && !ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (client._stream.CanRead)
            {
                var inBytes = await client.ReadAsync(bufferSize, ct);
                foreach (var b in inBytes)
                {
                    await decoder.AddByte(b);
                }

                await decoder.Flush();
            }
        }
        Disconnect(connectionId);
```

Any suggestion and help would be appreciable!

Comment: SignalR does not use the telnet protocol. It uses HTTP/WebSocket protocols.

Comment: SignalR is being used to keep the server alive and code behind connects the tcp client ?

Comment: So your communication is over a raw TCP/IP socket, and not SignalR?

Comment: Yes, can say. But HUB is being used to connects through telnet to IP

Comment: @StephenCleary do you think if we can overcome this issue , as I have tried with few code samples but it did not work.

Comment: I don't understand how SignalR is being used to connect raw sockets. I suspect that you just have regular SignalR connections, which are not compatible with telnet.

Comment: @StephenCleary , hi Stephen issue got fixed long back forgot to update here, it was the bytes were empty so the loop keep looking for empty bytes. Is it possible that two user can access tcpclient at same time ?

Comment: I'm still not clear on how SignalR can connect to telnet. With raw sockets, a zero-byte read indicates a closed connection. And two connected users would have two independent connections.

Comment: @StephenCleary i think could be a problem I may not be able to explain and so it goes wrong. SignalR is being used to keep the server connection alive so we can keep getting bytes from the tcpClient. As tcpClient keeps sending data and we wanted it to be reflected to client on  web portal. No we want to connect to tcpClient with two different machines connecting to same IP and port  is it possible ? Since it is not working with me when one user is connected already other also connects but does not read stream.

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense. It's not possible for SignalR to keep a TcpClient connection alive.